# PHP/Smarty - Random Session data loss between 2 pages

Tags: php, session, smarty, loss

I'm facing the weirdest issue I've ever seen with PHP. I will try to be really exhaustive because each detail can count.

I have 3 PHP pages, and their HTML is generated using Smarty. They all call `session_start()` at their top.

- the first page can be heavy to load, it displays a big amount of clickable pictures that are previews of PHP complex objects
- if a picture is chosen it leads to the second page with a specific URL.This page will generate a PHP object related to the URL info (so this page does not need info from previous page to work. If you copy-paste this URL at anytime it will work). This object will be stored into `$_SESSION` with a unique id.
- the third page is included as an img src in the second page's HTML code (generated with Smarty). This is a PHP page having the object's session id in URL parameter and reading the object's info in $_SESSION, creating it's image preview and turns into an image with header('Content-type: image/jpeg').

To sum up :
heavy first page => second page creating and storing a PHP object into `$_SESSION` => third page, included in second page's HTML code, searching for this object and creating a preview.

The problem is, sometimes, this third page is trying to load the object in `$_SESSION` and it's just not there !

Some facts :

- the problem never occurs when the second page is loaded as a stand-alone with its own URL
- the problem only occurs randomly when the heavy first page starts loading images and we furiously click on one of the first ones to appear
- whatever the situation is, if I dump my `$_SESSION` variables at the very end of the second page I can ALWAYS see the generated object in my session

So it seems that the issue is located between the very end of the second page and the beginning of the third, but all of this related to the activity of the first one !
All I know is that it is linked to a fast navigation between pages.

I've tried almost everything :

- `session_write_close()` everywhere it's possible (at the end of my pages before/after smarty display, then at the beginning before `session_start()`)
- add `exit()` at the end of my scripts
- even `sleep(1)` at the beginning of the third in case session close operation needs more time

Nothing works. I have no more clues ... Maybe Smarty ? Maybe some odd PHP session behaviour  named bug #4454 somewhere ?

Thanks a lot in advance for helping me with this.

Edit : piece of code after `serialize()` chat

```
/* ===== Page2.php ===== */

/*creating object $card and setting some values ...*/

/*calling the function that gives the card preview*/
$assigns['front'] = $card->getPreviewURL();

/*other stuff ... assign $assigns to smarty ... etc*/


/* ===== Card object class ===== */

function getPreviewURL()
{
  $_SESSION['products'][$this->getObjectId()] = serialize($this);
  $url = '/page3.php?s='.$this->getObjectId();
  return $url;
}


/* ===== Page2.html ===== */

img src="{$front}" alt="toto"


/* ===== Page3.php ===== */

/*getting id value and reading session*/

if(!empty($_GET['s'])) {
  session_write_close();
  $session = new Session;
  if(!empty($_SESSION['products'][$_GET['s']])) {
     $product = unserialize($_SESSION['products'][$_GET['s']]);
  }
  else {
     log('$_SESSION[products]['.$_GET['s'].'] does NOT exist');
     header("Status: 404 Not Found");
     exit;
  }
}
```

and when bug occurs, I get :

```
page2.php debug log :
Session value : [o20aee110e0853e74da4d17c9b7ab3075]=>O:8:"Postcard":19:{s:4:"tmpl";O:16:"PostcardTemplate":20:{s:2:"id";s:3:"152";s:2:"or";i:0;s:3:"ord";s:2:"14";s:11:"description";s:0:"" ... etc
```

```
page3.php debug log :
$_SESSION[products][o20aee110e0853e74da4d17c9b7ab3075] does NOT exist
```

Comment: Make sure `error_reporting` is `E_ALL` and look for notices/errors/warnings on pages 2 & 3. I would open page 2 in a tab and page 3 in another and then just keep trying. Don't show the image on page 3, but dump the `$_SESSION` data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably, the problem is, that PHP tries to unserialize your object but cannot find the class definition.

You can do one of the following two things:

[serialize()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php) the object manually before you put it into the session and [unserialize()](http://ch2.php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php) it after you loaded the class definition.

Or: Use [autoloading](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php).

Comment: That's exactly what PHP sessions do anyway, so there's really no point.

Comment: @Rudie: Yes, and because it does it automatically, it gets unserialized before the class definition is loaded.

Comment: That makes sense... Sort of... PHP must be smarter than that! Why does it work sometimes?

Comment: @Rudie: This is a good question. it's possible PHP unserializes the data once it is first accessed, I do not know the implementation details. I will try to reproduce it.

Comment: Should be easy to find: `Array
(
    [test] => __PHP_Incomplete_Class Object
        (
            [__PHP_Incomplete_Class_Name] => Oele
        )

)`

Comment: Hello guys, thanks for your replies.
If I dump my session variables, the object is just not there ([object_id]=>object_data is just missing :/).
But I will try serialize() anyway, it can't hurt.

Comment: @Bedu33: Remember to also unserialize it when you need it. If you still have issues, I recommend you post a shortened version of your code so we can try and reproduce the issue.

Comment: Bug is still there using serialize()/unserialize() even if I have the impression it occurs less than before.
I've edited my post with pieces of code. Hope this can help.